# Weird non-existent namespaces shown in doxygen class list... type libraries?

Tags: doxygen

I've been confused by empty namespaces listed in my doxygen output, when our codebase doesn't even use namespaces (sensitive names redacted):

[image: doxygen class list]

The weird thing is these *almost* match project/class names in our codebase, but not quite. Most of these strings do *not exist anywhere* in our codebase.

However I did spot that we *do* have type library (.tlb) files matching several of these 'namespaces':

[image]

**update** : today I realised that this is due to `library` declarations in ODL files being documented as namespaces. But I don't know how to control this.

Comment: Did you use the latest doxygen version (1.8.3.1)?

Comment: 1.8.something :) only got it a few weeks ago. I've identified the problem as being `library` declarations in ODL files just today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I determined that these namespaces were from IDL library declarations... e.g anytime in an ODL files I had `library ObjectServerLib` I got a namespace in doxygen.

My only solution was a combination of file-name and symbol name exclusion patterns and excluding a few individual symbols that didn't meet any naming convention.

I couldn't see a way to stop this `library` namespace documentation happening completely.